# How to select values from an array or a List<Type> within a lowIndex and a HighIndex value?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have two collection variables as follows:

```
public static int[] intArray = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
public static List<int> intList = new List<int>(); //The list also has same elements as the array.
```

What I want to do is: Select values based on range values of indexes.

Example: If I want to choose values 3(inclusive) to 8(inclusive) from both the variables, then I need to access them using the indexes within a range of some integer values like this =>

```
intArray.getValuesByRange(3,5); // pseudo code
```

NOTE: Same applies to the intList.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are wanting range by element index or element value? The question seems to allude to *by element value* but your title implies *by element index*.

Comment: @Igor I have tried arrayName.getRange() and arrayName.getSegment() methods but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: @IAbstract I want values by the element indexes

Comment: Then unless I am missing something else, @TvanB should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

intArray can be parsed to a List via the `.ToList()` method. Lists have a method called `GetRange(int index, int count)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much for your suggestions and answers. I really appreciate your time and the knowledge shared. After some stress on my program, I found a simple way to achieve the desired functionality. Here's my C# code below:

```
class Program
{
   //Author         : Mudrak Patel
   //Github username: mudrakpatel

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> intList = new List<int>();
        List<double> doubleList = new List<double>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++)
        {
            intList.Add(index);
            doubleList.Add((double)index);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nAll elements of integer array\n--------------------------------------------------------");
        DisplayArray(intList.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("\nAll elements of double array\n--------------------------------------------------------");
        DisplayArray(doubleList.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("\nAll elements of integer array from 3rd place to 8th place\n--------------------------------------------------------");
        DisplayArray(intList.ToArray(), 3, 8);
        Console.WriteLine("\nAll elements of double array from 3rd place to 8th place\n--------------------------------------------------------");
        DisplayArray(doubleList.ToArray(), 3, 8);
    }

    //Overloaded DisplayArray method
   public static void DisplayArray<Type>(Type[] inputCollectionObject)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < inputCollectionObject.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0,2}", inputCollectionObject[index]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void DisplayArray<Type>(Type[] inputCollectionObject, int lowIndex , int highIndex)
    {
        var selectedElements = new List<int>();
        for (int index = lowIndex; index < highIndex; index++)
        {
            selectedElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(inputCollectionObject[index]));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The elements within the range you specified:\n--------------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var element in selectedElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0,2}", element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `lowIndex` is inclusive. Did you want your `highIndex` inclusive as well? If so then you need to use `index <= highIndex`.

Comment: @IAbstract I used `index < highIndex` because highIndex is exclusive, unlike `lowIndex`, Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ and a combination of [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = intArray.Skip(3).Take(6).ToArray();
```

It will also work for intList .

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is requesting. If I understand the question, the OP wants a range of values not indices.

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE**: Upon clarification from the OP, it is the elements by indices that is desired. The following solution provides elements by value range. I am choosing to leave this for anyone who may end up finding it useful.

<strike>I think</strike> [T]he following <strike>would</strike> will work:

```
var fromArray = intArray.SkipWhile(i => i < lower).TakeWhile(i => i <= upper).ToArray();
var fromList = intList.SkipWhile(i => i < lower).TakeWhile(i => i <= upper).ToList();
```

`GetRange(...)` method works on the element indices of an `IList<T>` and doesn't sound like what you are wanting.

The sample above could easily be an extension method on `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetValueRange(this IEnumerable<int> source, int lower, int upper) {
    return source.SkipWhile(i => i < lower).TakeWhile(i => i <= upper);
}
```

...with some care you could make the extension method work for any struct value by replacing `<int>` with `<T>` and then applying a `where T : struct` constraint.

**Edit**
Made a correction on my previously *untested* code with the following:

```
class Program
{
    private static int[] intArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rangeVals = intArray.GetValueRange(3, 8);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", rangeVals.Select(i => $"{i}")));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetValueRange(this IEnumerable<int> source, int lower, int upper) {
        return source.SkipWhile(i => i < lower).TakeWhile(i => i <= upper);
    }

}
```

Output:

> 3,4,5,6,7,8

*A note on performance*: depending on how large your array of numbers is expected to be, you may want to consider `Sort`ing. If there are 1,000 numbers in random order, this function will take much longer to execute than if the values were already sorted.

Comment: The solution won't work - TakeWhile returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true.  i >= 3 && i <= 5 is not true for the first element.